# How do I center inline-blocks?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how I can center inline-blocks. Any help?
I tried doing `margin-top: x em;` but all it did was have the image go down. This inline-block is deliberately inside an image block. If you have links that show me how to position inline-blocks, I will gladly take them into consideration, as I am still learning how to do CSS and HTML.

```css
#img-banner article {
  border: solid thick white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14em;
  position: static;
}

#img-banner h1 {
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 27px;
}
```

```html
<span id="img-banner">
    <article>
    <h1>Introduction</h1>
    </article>
    </span>
```

Comment: Your HTML in invalid. An `<article>` can't be a child of a `<span>`

Comment: You talk about an image, but there is no image to be found in your example code.

Comment: Oh, the `img-banner` had its own css code for a background image.

Answer (score 0):

It would be important that you include the properties of the containing span as this is the parent you need to align on. Assuming you want to **vertically** center your element, you need to ask yourself if the height of your containing element is known and that will guide you towards the proper centering technique.

https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

You will find alot of common centering techniques on this website. You can consider your inline-block element as a block-level element.

Personally, I like making sure my container is `position:relative` and then add `top:50%; transform: translateY(-50%)` to my unknown height positioned elements.

**Edit :** As noted in your comments, this HTML is invalid. Only **inline** elements are allowed in a span. I don't know why I overlooked this.

Comment: Thank you! Found out what do on here, but I have another question. Why can't `article` be a child of `span`?

Comment: `article` categorizes as `Flow content` in the HTML specifications. `span` only permits `Phrasing content` within itself.

Phrasing content : https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2